# How many MLB players have hit 4 or more Home Runs in a game?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, records

On June 6th, 2017, Scooter Gennett hit 4 home runs to become the first Cincinnati Red ever to do so.

Who are the other people who have hit at least 4 HRs in a single game? Please provide name and the date of the occurrence.

Comment: Not the list, but the number is now 15; source [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/FNojw), stolen from [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/16220/6126).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MLB.com](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/history/rare_feats/index.jsp?feature=four_homer_game), it's been done 17 times, and here is a list of all Players who have hit 4 Homeruns in a game:

- Scooter Gennett, Cincinnati   06-06-2017
- Josh Hamilton, Texas  05-08-2012
- Carlos Delgado, Toronto   09-25-2003
- Shawn Green, Los Angeles  05-23-2002
- Mike Cameron, Seattle 05-02-2002
- Mark Whiten, St. Louis    09-07-1993
- Bob Horner, Atlanta   07-06-1986
- Mike Schmidt, Philadelphia    04-17-1976
- Willie Mays, San Francisco    04-30-1961
- Rocky Colavito, Cleveland 06-10-1959
- Joe Adcock, Milwaukee 07-31-1954
- Gil Hodges, Brooklyn  08-31-1950
- Pat Seerey, Chicago   07-18-1948
- Chuck Klein, Philadelphia 07-10-1936
- Lou Gehrig, New York  06-03-1932
- Ed Delahanty, Philadelphia    07-13-1896
- Bobby Lowe, Boston    05-30-1894